# How can I send a data field to a javascript function?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo-ui grid.

My grid fill with ajax method.

No I have to pass primary key field value to a method as parameter.

I used a code same as this :

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data, <#= UserId #>)#");
```

but my javascript methode doesnt fire.

But if I use this :

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data)#");
```

It will run. Actually without input parameter.

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(UserId)#");
```

Everything inside the #= # block is executed as a JavaScript statement. The current data item is the context and UserId will be resolved properly. The generated code is something like this:

```
var output = "";

with (dataItem) {
  output += renderNumber(UserId); // UserId is properly evaluated thanks to the with operator.
}
```